# Sticky div script not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to use the following sticky div script which works fine in all browsers except chrome. I've tested it so far on IE6, 7, 8 and Firefox.

Has anybody a brief idea on why?

below is the JavaScript code...

```
var offsetfromedge=0      //offset from window edge when content is "docked". Change if desired.
var dockarray=new Array() //array to cache dockit instances
var dkclear=new Array()   //array to cache corresponding clearinterval pointers

function dockit(el, duration){
this.source=document.all? document.all[el] : document.getElementById(el);
this.source.height=this.source.offsetHeight;
this.docheight=truebody().clientHeight;
this.duration=duration;
this.pagetop=0;
this.elementoffset=this.getOffsetY();
dockarray[dockarray.length]=this;
var pointer=eval(dockarray.length-1);
var dynexpress='dkclear['+pointer+']=setInterval("dockornot(dockarray['+pointer+'])",100);';
dynexpress=(this.duration>0)? dynexpress+'setTimeout("clearInterval(dkclear['+pointer+']); dockarray['+pointer+'].source.style.top=0", duration*1000)' : dynexpress;
eval(dynexpress);
}

dockit.prototype.getOffsetY=function(){
var totaloffset=parseInt(this.source.offsetTop);
var parentEl=this.source.offsetParent;
while (parentEl!=null){
totaloffset+=parentEl.offsetTop;
parentEl=parentEl.offsetParent;
}
return totaloffset;
}

function dockornot(obj){
obj.pagetop=truebody().scrollTop;
if (obj.pagetop>obj.elementoffset) //detect upper offset
obj.source.style.top=obj.pagetop-obj.elementoffset+offsetfromedge+"px";
else if (obj.pagetop+obj.docheight<obj.elementoffset+parseInt(obj.source.height)) //lower offset
obj.source.style.top=obj.pagetop+obj.docheight-obj.source.height-obj.elementoffset-offsetfromedge+"px";
else
obj.source.style.top=0;
}

function truebody(){
return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}
```

and I'm using the following tutorial
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/dockcontent.htm

Comment: Well, the demo in that page doesnt seem to work in chrome at all... I suggest you take a look at my answer here and especially the bottom part of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215728/lock-a-div-on-the-screen-after-so-much-of-it-has-scrolled-off/7215805#7215805

Comment: its also not working in safari btw

Answer (score 0):

try to put the JS code at the end of the html file and not into the head tags, sometimes browser load the pages sequentially and sometimes that makes some error